# Target a buried div in google Charts to alter attributes

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to fix an error that Google Charts has caused by what I assume is them ceasing support of a feature. The following code is my Google Chart. Pretty straight forward. I need to target a specific `div` buried in the code of the Google Chart though, because my dev page on BigCommerce is getting an added window scroll bar with the basic chart code in mobile. [Inspected version of the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4eHj.jpg)

I highlighted the `div` to be targeted and the attribute that needs to change on the right. It needs to be `-100%` instead of `-10000px` I have tried numerous paths to this, but nothing has worked. I am in no way an expert at JS. I'm still learning the basics as I build and fix things, so I wouldn't be surprised if I wrote this all wrong. The last attempt I made was this:

```
function fixTable() {

    var chartSize = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="A tabular representation of the data in the chart."]');

    chartSize.style.position = unset;
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```js
google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart', 'line'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStageOne);

var options = {
    backgroundColor: '#555',
    color: '#fff',
    chartArea: {
        left: 40,
        top: 50,
        bottom: 40,
        width: "100%",
        height: "99%",
    },
    titleTextStyle: {
        color: 'white'
    },
    hAxis: {
        viewWindowMode: 'maximized',
        minValue: 3000,
        maxValue: 7000,
        minorGridlines: {
            count: 4
        },
        ticks: [3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000],
        textStyle: {
            color: 'white'
        },
        titleTextStyle: {
            color: 'white'
        }
    },
    vAxis: {
        viewWindowMode: 'maximized',
        minValue: 50,
        maxValue: 300,
        minorGridlines: {
            count: 4
        },
        ticks: [50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300],
        textStyle: {
            color: 'white'
        },
        titleTextStyle: {
            color: 'white'
        }
    },
    colors: ['#ffffff', '#C04D00', '#ffffff', '#C04D00'],
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: {
        position: 'top',
        textStyle: {
            color: 'white'
        }
    },
    series: {
        0: {
            lineWidth: 3,
            lineDashStyle: [16, 6]
        },
        1: {
            lineWidth: 3,
            lineDashStyle: [12, 5]
        },
        2: {
            lineWidth: 5,
        },
        3: {
            lineWidth: 5,
        }
    },
};

function drawStageOne() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'OEM Torque (max 266)');
    data.addColumn('number', 'OEM HP (max 247)');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Intercooler Torque (max 269)');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Intercooler HP (max 253)');

    data.addRows([
        [3000, 195, 111, 182, 104],
        [3250, 266, 164, 269, 166],
        [3500, 260, 174, 268, 179],
        [3750, 259, 185, 265, 189],
        [4000, 258, 196, 264, 201],
        [4250, 249, 202, 250, 202],
        [4500, 245, 210, 250, 214],
        [4750, 244, 221, 247, 224],
        [5000, 248, 236, 247, 235],
        [5250, 240, 240, 242, 242],
        [5500, 233, 244, 236, 247],
        [5750, 224, 245, 228, 249],
        [6000, 218, 247, 224, 253],
        [6250, 205, 243, 207, 246],
        [6500, 190, 235, 193, 238],
        [6750, 178, 229, 182, 235],
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('stageOneDev'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}

$(window).resize(function(){
  drawStageOne();
  drawStageTwo();
});
```

```css
.googlechart {
  width: 100%; 
  min-height: 550px;
}
```

```html
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
</head>
<div id="stageOneDev" class="googlechart">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but it seems to work. I added the ready event handler as well as a timer function that gives an extra 100ms to wait for the chart to fully render. You may have to experiment with that value a bit. Not ideal, but there doesn't seem to be an event available that fires when everything in the chart is done.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .googlechart {
            width: 100%; 
            min-height: 550px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="stageOneDev" class="googlechart">&nbsp;</div>
    <script>
google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart', 'line'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStageOne);

var options = {
    backgroundColor: '#555',
    color: '#fff',
    chartArea: {
        left: 40,
        top: 50,
        bottom: 40,
        width: "100%",
        height: "99%",
    },
    titleTextStyle: {
        color: 'white'
    },
    hAxis: {
        viewWindowMode: 'maximized',
        minValue: 3000,
        maxValue: 7000,
        minorGridlines: {
            count: 4
        },
        ticks: [3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000],
        textStyle: {
            color: 'white'
        },
        titleTextStyle: {
            color: 'white'
        }
    },
    vAxis: {
        viewWindowMode: 'maximized',
        minValue: 50,
        maxValue: 300,
        minorGridlines: {
            count: 4
        },
        ticks: [50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300],
        textStyle: {
            color: 'white'
        },
        titleTextStyle: {
            color: 'white'
        }
    },
    colors: ['#ffffff', '#C04D00', '#ffffff', '#C04D00'],
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: {
        position: 'top',
        textStyle: {
            color: 'white'
        }
    },
    series: {
        0: {
            lineWidth: 3,
            lineDashStyle: [16, 6]
        },
        1: {
            lineWidth: 3,
            lineDashStyle: [12, 5]
        },
        2: {
            lineWidth: 5,
        },
        3: {
            lineWidth: 5,
        }
    },
};

function drawStageOne() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'OEM Torque (max 266)');
    data.addColumn('number', 'OEM HP (max 247)');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Intercooler Torque (max 269)');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Intercooler HP (max 253)');

    data.addRows([
        [3000, 195, 111, 182, 104],
        [3250, 266, 164, 269, 166],
        [3500, 260, 174, 268, 179],
        [3750, 259, 185, 265, 189],
        [4000, 258, 196, 264, 201],
        [4250, 249, 202, 250, 202],
        [4500, 245, 210, 250, 214],
        [4750, 244, 221, 247, 224],
        [5000, 248, 236, 247, 235],
        [5250, 240, 240, 242, 242],
        [5500, 233, 244, 236, 247],
        [5750, 224, 245, 228, 249],
        [6000, 218, 247, 224, 253],
        [6250, 205, 243, 207, 246],
        [6500, 190, 235, 193, 238],
        [6750, 178, 229, 182, 235],
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('stageOneDev'));
    //add ready event listener
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', fixTable)
    chart.draw(data, options);
    
}
function fixTable() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const unset = "-100%";
        const chartSize = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="A tabular representation of the data in the chart."]');
        if (chartSize.length > 0) {
            chartSize[0].style.position = unset;
        }
    }, 100);
}


window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    drawStageOne();
});
                
            
            

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @Mifo!  I had to do a slight modification to your setup, but you gave me the foundation I needed.  I only adjusted "-100%" to "unset" to get it to work.  I thought the -100% would do it, but targeting the "left:" attribute doesn't seem to work live.